# How to capture an android application's onPause event?

Tags: android

My android application is consists of 20+ activities. I want to perform some task when application is in background (not an specific activity) and want to perform some other task when application is resumed. How to do this? I couldn't find onPause() and onResume() methods in Application class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it globally because an application is just a set of activities that function pretty much independently from each other.  The notion of something being in the background is really just that period when an activity is between `onPause()` and `onDestroy()`.

One way for you to do what you're after would be to develop a bit of code that keeps track of when the first of your activities sees an `onResume()` and when the last of them sees an `onPause()` and uses those conditions to perform your tasks.  You'd have to keep your data in a persisted store, such as shared preferences, so it doesn't vanish when the activity that created it gets destroyed.